# Raspberry PI 3B+ will not reboot after removing power

Tags: boot, sd-card, power, raspbian-buster, corrupt

Help! - I'm completely new to Raspberry. Today I have succesfully imaged the latest OS to the SD that came with my Raspberry PI 3 model B+. Everything works fine when I boot it up. I can also succesfully reboot from the raspberry itself. However when I try to remove power after shutting down it refuses to reboot and I have to reimage all over again.

I did wait for the yellow leds to go off after flickering 10 times before removing power. I also tried by sudo poweroff but no difference. I formatted the SD card that came with my raspberry. I found multiple threads on this issue and how finicky this can be but most users appears to be OK if they just wait for it to properly shut down?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

config.txt:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

cmdline:

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=9537680d-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles usbhid.mousepoll=0
```

Comment: I've also tried another SD card with the same result.

Comment: Measure the voltage between pin#1 and the outside case of the USB. Measure the voltage between pin#2 and the USB. First voltage should be 3.3V, second should be 5V. If the 3.3V is missing then you've blown the PMIC and you'll need to replace your 3B+ with a RPi4B8GB.

Comment: What does the green led do when you try to boot?

Comment: Between pin #1 and USB is 3.29V and between pin#2 and USB is 5.18V. With USB I assume you mean the outside of the micro USB power connector? I measure it on the outside of the female port when I remove the plastic casting.

The green LED bleeps twice when I connect it - then flickers a bit and subsequently goes out.

Comment: So you do "sudo shutdown now", and then wait for LED activity to finish before removing power?

Comment: I did not do "sudo shutdown now" but "sudo poweroff". Otherwise I just use the shut down from the menu.

First time I did not wait for the LEDs to finish I think - but I reimaged the SD a couple of times and on subsequent tries waited for the LED to finish before pulling the plug. It makes no difference. Longest wait was 10 minutes or something between shutting down and cutting power.

After reimaging everything works suberb including reboot. Until I try to shut down and the remove power after LEDs finish. It then does not reboot anymore. LED bleeps twice, flickers and then dies.

Comment: I do add "usbhid.mousepoll=0" to cmdline.txt - can that have anything to do with it? I add it right after reimaging to the SD and it boots up fine when I then put it in the Raspberry for the first time.

Comment: When you say it fails to boot do you get any lights or messages on the screen?  Can you show you config.txt in the question please?

Comment: I am wondering if after disconnecting the power, there was damage done. If so, you may want to restart fresh again.

Comment: The screen does not respond at all. Config and cmdline below.

I hope it is not damaged -  removing the power cable should not just damage the device but who knows. Not sure why it only happens on a power off. 

Symptoms seem to correspond with a corrupt SD.

Comment: I've added code tags to the files for you.  I cannot see why the mouse would impact a reboot - maybe try a Raspberry Pi 
OS Lite first with just the keyboard and monitor (no changes to config.txt),  boot up, expand disk using raspi-config, reboot, `sudo shutdown now`, wait a minute or so and power back on.  What type of mouse do you have that's causing issues?

Comment: I'm going to try that tomorrow - it's just a standard wireless speedlink mouse. For some reason it responds reallllly slow and delayed on default setting with the raspberry OS on default. The keyboard mousepad works normal with default.

Thanks for all the help - fingers crossed.